# What does "requestTime" number mean in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

According [Chrome DevTools Protocol viewer](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#type-ResourceTiming) the value of `requestTime` is a baseline in seconds. To understand it I took this value from few web pages and for all of them the value of `requestTime` was unexpectedly large. For example one of them was 13133423 seconds. Does anyone know why the value of `requestTime` is too large? And what `requestTime` value mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [source code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/platform/loader/fetch/resource_load_timing.h;l=117;drc=28442cacc3be1a7d05a898aba663025a143095ac?sq=package:chromium):

> We want to present a unified timeline to Javascript. Using walltime is
>   problematic, because the clock may skew while resources load. To prevent
>   that skew, we record a single reference walltime when root document
>   navigation begins.
>
> All other times are recorded using
>   monotonicallyIncreasingTime().
>
> When a time needs to be presented to
>   Javascript, we build a pseudo-walltime using the following equation
>   (m_requestTime as example): `pseudo time = document wall reference + (m_requestTime - document monotonic reference)`
>
> All values from monotonicallyIncreasingTime(), in base::TimeTicks.

More info on monotonicallyIncreasingTime: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39634132